# How do you write a Boolean value when using XML writer in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create an XML file containing data from another source. However, at the moment XML readers are having trouble processing the Boolean values.  Is there a way to get around this issue?

I have had a look and couldn't come across a command to writeElementBollean :S

```
$enc = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding( $false )

# get an XMLTextWriter to create the XML
$XmlWriter = New-Object System.XMl.XmlTextWriter($Path,$enc)



# write the header
$xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument() 

$xmlWriter.WriteStartElement('InstanceTypes xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.citrix.com/2013/xd/AWSInstanceTypes InstanceTypes.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.citrix.com/2013/xd/AWSInstanceTypes"')

foreach($i in $testy){
    $XmlWriter.WriteStartElement('InstanceType')
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('Name',$i)
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('MemoryMiB',3888)
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('EC2ComputeUnits',2)
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('VirtualCores',2)
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('InstanceStorageGB',120)
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('IOPerformance',2)

#####BOOLEAN Value need for the EBS Optimised Available
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('EBSOptimisedAvailable',$true)
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('APIName',$i)
    $xmlWriter.WriteElementString('NetworkPerformance','Normal')
    $xmlWriter.WriteEndElement()
}

$xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument()
$xmlWriter.Flush()
$xmlWriter.Close()
```

Comment: What does the resulting <ESBOptimisedAvailable> node look like when it gets written at the moment, and what are you expecting it to look like? And what problems are you having when trying to read the resulting xml (e.g. the exact error message, etc)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, boolean value should be lowercase so if your replace your line with `$xmlWriter.WriteElementString('EBSOptimisedAvailable', 'true')` that should be valid. 

That being said, I see

Comment: Also, using your current code, there's an error in the resulting XML. I get the end element looking like this `</InstanceTypes xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.citrix.com/2013/xd/AWSInstanceTypes InstanceTypes.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.citrix.com/2013/xd/AWSInstanceTypes">` 

It should simply be `</InstanceTypes>`. In the first place, you definitely will get error from any reader trying to read your version of the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

[XSD Miscellaneous Data Types](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_misc.asp) (w3schools.com) says:

> Boolean Data Type
>
> The boolean data type is used to specify a true or false value.
>
> The following is an example of a boolean declaration in a **schema**:

`<xs:attribute name="disabled" type="xs:boolean"/>`

> An element in your **document** might look like this:

`<prize disabled="true">999</prize>`

> Note: Legal values for boolean are true, false, 1 (which indicates
>   true), and 0 (which indicates false).